# Error while running java script in terminal using Node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal

This is the code i have written in my tut63.js file
`code`
console.log('Hello World');

when i type node tut63.js in terminal it was suppose to show " Hello World ".

But instead it is showing this error in terminal.
`code`
PS C:\Users\m\Desktop> node.tut63.js
The term 'node.tut63.js' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or oper
able program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is c
orrect and try again.
At line:1 char:14

- node.tut63.js <<<<

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node.tut63.js:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You need a space between `node` and `tut63.js` like this: `node tut63.js`  and you should be running this from the OS command shell.  To verify that things are configured correctly, you should be able to run `node -v` and see the version of nodejs printed out.

Comment: You need to put space between node and tut63.js

Comment: i am using Node.js version--node-v13.14.0-x64 in windows 7.

Comment: after trying node tut63.js also it is not working.